# Twilio Voice - Add a person to an exisiting confrence call

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio Voice, Now what i want to do is, If i already created a conference call between 2 people, and then while they are talking, they decided to add a 3rd person to the call with them on the conference, Can someone please help me how to have this done with a sample or something ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. So, it depends on how this is setup. I presume your conference call [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) looks like this:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Conference>someroom</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

In that case, you can just have another person dial the number and provide the same TwiML to add them to the same conference room. If you want the people on the call to invite someone in, you will need to use  so that they can provide the other person's number, or have some sort of web interface. Then use the REST API to dial that person into the conference, again with the same TwiML.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: I wanted to have the conference moderator to be able to add more ppl using his phone (by pressing some number then he get asked to insert the phone number of the new person then etc..), Did not knw how, I ended up doing it by having him adding that person using a web browser (We already initiate the calls from there). Thanks!