# In Twilio voice, how do I make TWO outgoing calls and connect both together?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, phone-call

I want to programmatically make two outgoing calls using the Java Twilio API.  What I have so so far is as following:

I registered two numbers with twilio. The I execute the following code to make the first outgoing call:

```
        val call = Call.creator(
                PhoneNumber(numberOne), // TO
                PhoneNumber(TWILIO_NUMBER0), // FROM
                URI.create(twilioInformURL(id)) // INSTRUCTIONS for when person picks up
        ).setMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
         .setStatusCallback(twilioStatusURL(id))
         .setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
         .setStatusCallbackEvent(listOf("initiated", "in-progress", "ringing", "answered", "completed"))
         .create()
```

This will call numberOne number from TWILIO_NUMBER0, then do an API POST Call to my URL where I return the following to make the second call:

```
        val number = Number.Builder(numberTwo).build()
        val dial = Dial.Builder().number(number).build()
        val response = VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build()
        return response.toXml()
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It just calls and reads out numberTwo.

If anyone knows how to make this work I would really appreciate it.

Comment: the two twilio numbers will call another regular phone number? like a conference?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea Yes call other regular numbers. Like a conference, but in a conference you dial in. Here I want to dial out the participates.

Comment: Being more than 2 numbers involved makes it a conference, regardless who is calling. I would suggest using https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319509/twilio-voice-add-a-person-to-an-exisiting-confrence-call to see how to call a person to join a conference

Comment: Do you have a webhook handler set up for your second number? What TwiML does it return? What do you expect to happen when these two Twilio numbers connect?

Comment: @philnash I have no webhooks for receiving calls. I'm trying to connect two outside numbers using two twilio numbers. I want the simplest possible solution.

Comment: Oh! I know what it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If Twilio is just reading out your number then you are likely not serving the TwiML as XML. If Twilio doesn't see a `Content-Type` header of `text/xml` or `application/xml` then it assumes text content and reads out the text contents of the elements.

Make sure you are setting your `Content-Type` header in the webhook response and this should work.

Comment: Changed from  text/plain to Content-Type application/xml and it worked, thank you!